# Laravel 5.0 breaks as soon as I try to composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, homestead

I have Laravel 5.0.34 project that works perfectly fine, but recently I had to install another plugin and realized that as soon as I try to run

```
composer update
```

in my root directory, it gives the error

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

I have tried removing the post-update-cmd section of my composer.json, but all that does is removes the error from popping up on the command-line. It still gives an error when I try to display the project though.

I have also tried deleting `storage/framework/compiled`, but found that I don't have that file/directory

This person seemed to have the same issue, but none of their fixes worked for me

http://laravel.io/forum/03-25-2015-composer-update-throwing-error-script-php-artisan-optimize-handling-the-post-update-cmd-event-returned-with-an-error

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the full error by running `composer update -v`

Comment: The full error is here: `http://imgur.com/a/GpMfi`

Comment: Any ideas of how to fix it, @DovBenyominSohacheski?

Comment: check your app.php in the config file and let me know if any of the service providers are unrecognized. Can you run any `artisan` commands?

Comment: What do you mean by unrecognized? And yes, artisan commands work perfectly. Thanks for the help @DovBenyominSohacheski